# Donate via PayPal button against Google policy?

Tags: java, android, paypal, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Is there a definite answer on if a PayPal donate button is allowed or disallowed?  I see:

- many SO threads saying to be cautious when integrating a PayPal donate button
- many SO threads with examples of apps getting banned
- and also many SO threads of people giving the answer how to do it without any warning that they are breaking T&C

Would PayPal actually have a donate button/SDK available if they new it would violate Google's T&C?  I don't think I will personally do it unless I could get a 100% answer since I am afraid of losing my app.  Of course we all know why I want a donate button and that is to get around the 30% cut from Google.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about law/Google policy/etc.

Comment: Where are these questions posted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html#payments

and

http://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html#pricing-payments

They should help you :-)

Comment: Yup. These two headings should make it abundantly clear. **1: App purchases** and **2: In-app purchases**.

Comment: Yea I think so too.  Just confused why PayPal would make it available to implement their PayPal donate button if they know that is breaking Google rules.

Comment: @Matt: PayPal has nothing to loose and they aren't directly breaking the rules either. It is us, the dev's, that suffer the consequences. Besides, if your app is not distributed via Google Play, then PayPal is a good alternative.